# Domain of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two questions about the domain of differential equations.

1. I have a linear differential equation $$y' + \frac{y}{x} = x^2$$

and initial condition $y(1)=1$. I am solving this differential equation on interval $J=(0,\infty)$. $1/x$ is continuous on two intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ and $x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, initial condition belongs to $(0,\infty)$, so I chose this interval.

The solution is $y=\frac{x^3}{4} + \frac{c}{x}$ and with initial condition $y=\frac{x^3}{4} + \frac{3}{4x}$

I want to ask you, domain is $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ or only $(0,\infty)$? I think it is $(0,\infty)$, because I chose interval J as that while I was solving this differential equation with integral method.

2. I have equation with separated variables
   $$x*y'+y=y^2$$

When I want to make that separation, I have to divide by $x$. So $x!=0$. And my qustion is, do I have to include that condition in the final domain? The solution is $y=\frac{1}{1-xc}$. And do I have to include this condition also to solution $y=0$ and $y=1$? Or they can stay $x=R$?

thx

Comment: Edited. Is it better?

Comment: Use `\infty` for infinity sign.

Comment: is it acceptable now?

Comment: I have one question, what are the domains of solutions y=0 and y=1. And what is the basic domain for solution. Everything goes with the second question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Yes. Only the coefficients of the normalized equation determine the maximal interval. Or said another way, the equation is singular at the roots of the leading coefficient, these separate the possible domains.

   Yes, you also have to include the constant solutions. If you replace the constant by an initial condition, these cases should appear automatically in the formula.

Comment: 1. ok, so domain of y is $x=(0,\infty)$
2. I have read some materials on the internet ans when make the separation, there is this condition x!=0, but in the assignment, it can be x=0. So I dont have to "delete" x=0 from domain?

Comment: $x=0$ is definitely a singular point, as the equation there is no longer a differential equation. That one can find solutions on both sides having the same formula does not change that fact. Usually almost all so combined solutions that have a finite value pass through the same point at $x=0$, which is not surprising as $y(0)=y(0)^2$ only has the solutions $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Can you please confirm me, that domain in 1. is $x=(0,\infty)$ and not $(-\infty,0)U(0,\infty)$? And in 2., how sould I then write the domain? now I have for c<0: $(-\infty,1/c)$ and $(1/c,\infty)$, same for c>0.And this equation have two singular solutions y(x)=0 and y(x)=1, are those defined for all real numbers or not?

Comment: 1. Yes, the domain is always *one* open interval. 2. No, the domain of the *ODE solution* can not cross $0$, and also not $1/c$. It depends on the initial point which interval of this subdivision is the domain of the solution.

Comment: How should I write it? And the singular solutions y(x)=0 and y(x)=1 are defined on all real numbers?

Comment: A solution can not leave the domain of a DE, even if it has a limit at the boundary of that domain. The constant solutions are no special cases there.